# Where to read diary from Wings (Amiga game)

Tags: amiga

There was a nice WWI flight game from Cinemaware on the Amiga called Wings. Between the sections of the game was a diary which was actually quite a good read. I never played the game to the end and didn't get a chance to read the full diary. I wonder if the diary can be found on the internet somewhere as I want to finish it (20 years later...)?

Comment: Just getting nostalgic here... damn that was a great game, I'm not sure if I ever finished it either, but do recall playing it a lot.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The site *Recorded Amiga Games* has a long play of Wings here: [AMIGA LONGPLAY #378 - WINGS](http://recordedamigagames.ath.cx/modules/tinycontent/index.php?id=508).

It should contain all the diary entries. But you have to pause it to read them. You may also want to skip ahead a little in the video since it's over 9 hours long.

You can either download it from the site or watch in on YouTube [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hL-qtxNgoHU).

Comment: Nine hour long video!? Seems like I'll be needing a lot of popcorn to go through that... I'm accepting this answer until something better comes up. Thanks.